# SQL view with count and group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tables `Address`, `Property` and `Listing`:

```
Create Table Listing
    ( PropertyID int  -- Property ID as per the Property table
    , AgentID int
    , ListingDate DateTime not null property
    , AskingPrice Decimal(10,2) not null 
    , SaleDate Date
    , SalePrice Decimal(10, 2)  
    , Primary Key (PropertyID, ListingDate)
    , Foreign Key (PropertyID) references Property(PropertyID)
    , Foreign Key (AgentID) references Agent(AgentID) on delete no action on update no action

Create Table Address
    ( AddressID int Primary Key
    , StreetAddress varchar (100)
    , City varchar (50)
    , StateCode char(3)
    , PostalCode char (12)
    , Country varchar(30)
    )
        )
Create Table Property 
    ( PropertyID int Primary Key -- Unique ID for each property
    , AddressID int references Address(AddressID) On Delete no action on update no action
    , NumberOfRooms int not null Check (NumberOfRooms > 0) -- Number of rooms
    )
```

I would like to create a view that will have the number of properties for sale in each city and their average price. Property is for sell when `AskingPrice` is not and `SaleDate = null`. The problem is that I can't get the count per city because I get error

> Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference

How do I solve this?

My code:

```
create view MarketStatistics as
select City = a.City,
     Properties = (select count(PropertyID)from Listing l where l.AskingPrice is not Null and l.SaleDate is Null group by a.City),
     AskingPrice = (select avg(AskingPrice)from Listing)
from Address a
join Property p on p.AddressID = a.AddressID
join Listing l on p.PropertyID = l.PropertyID
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query can be much more simple, it's enough to group without using subqueries:

```
select 
    a.City,
    count(*) as Properties,
    avg(l.AskingPrice) as AskingPrice 
from Address a
inner join Property p on p.AddressID = a.AddressID
inner join Listing l on p.PropertyID = l.PropertyID
where l.AskingPrice is not Null and l.SaleDate is Null
group by a.City
```

Comment: How is the condition `Property is for sell when AskingPrice is not and SaleDate = null` handled?

Comment: @AbhishekChaudhary You're right, forgot to add that. Included now.

Comment: :) I am actually a bit confused. The question states that properties for sale and their avg asking price is required but, the query that setlio has written doesn't contain null checks for Asking Price. Your query is perfect if null check is required for both the metrics but, if Asking Price needs to be calculated for all properties, a sub query would be required.

Comment: @AbhishekChaudhary Hmm, you may be right though my answer was accepted. I'll leave it to the asker and I gave +1 to you.

Comment: Yup :) The asker knows the requirements best.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need group by. Simple co-related query should work:

```
 create view MarketStatistics as
 select City = a.City,
 Properties = (select count(PropertyID)from Listing l join Property p on p.PropertyID = a.PropertyID where l.AskingPrice is not Null and l.SaleDate is Null and p.addressID = a.addressID),
 AskingPrice = (select avg(AskingPrice)from Listing l join Property p on p.PropertyID = a.PropertyID where p.addressID = a.addressID)
 from Address a
```

I am assuming that you need asking price for all properties as you have not placed a null check in your query for asking price.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding another column in subquery which is not an outer reference like :

```
create view MarketStatistics as
select City = a.City,
     Properties = (select count(PropertyID)from Listing l where l.AskingPrice is not Null and l.SaleDate is Null group by a.City, PropertyID),
     AskingPrice = (select avg(AskingPrice)from Listing)
from Address a
join Property p on p.AddressID = a.AddressID
join Listing l on p.PropertyID = l.PropertyID
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  create view MarketStatistics as
    select City = a.City,
    Properties = (select count(PropertyID)from Listing l where l.AskingPrice is not Null   and l.SaleDate is Null),
    AskingPrice = (select avg(AskingPrice)from Listing)
    from Address a
    join Property p on p.AddressID = a.AddressID
    join Listing l on p.PropertyID = l.PropertyID
    group by a.City
```

Answer (score 0):

`group by` must have atleast one column name which is in the `select statement`
So change the `sub-query` to

```
select count(PropertyID)
from Listing l where l.AskingPrice is not Null 
     and l.SaleDate is Null 
group by a.City, PropertyID
```